# Using the Contains method to filter multiple different lines of an input

Tags: java, bufferedreader, contains

I am reading a txt file using bufferedreader which contains rows of data. I am then trying to filter out rows of the text file based on multiple conditions. In this case, I want to skip lines starting with AA and lines starting with DD  The text file looks something like

```
AA  Data1
BB  Data2
CC  Data3
DD  Data4
AA  Data5
CC  Data6
```

My code so far recognizes that I want to skip both of these, however, for the row thats goes from DD to AA, it will skip the DD row, but then not recognize that I want to also skip the AA row below so. So the output of my program reads:

```
BB  Data2
CC  Data3
AA  Data5
CC  Data6
```

It gets rid of the first AA as desired, but leaves the second AA, because it got rid of the DD in the line before it.

Below is my current code:

```
     public static void main(String[] args){

    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("files/txtfile"));
        String line = null;
        String previousLine = null;

        for (line=br.readLine(); line != null;){
            if (previousLine != null) {
                if (line.contains("AA")||line.contains("DD")){
                    previousLine = br.readLine();
                }
                line= br.readLine();
            }
            System.out.println(previousLine);
            previousLine = line;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Any advice would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
import java.io.*;
public class tehMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try( BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("files/txtfile")) ) {
            for (String line=br.readLine(); line != null; line=br.readLine()) {
                if (line.contains("AA")||line.contains("DD"))
                    continue;
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do this...

```
while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
  if(!(line.contains("AA") || line.contains("DD"))) {
    System.out.println(line);
  }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain your answer?

Comment: This one still only catches the first line to be filtered but still returns the second line. In the text file i described it filters out "DD Data 4" but is returning the line "AA Data5" below it.

Comment: The while will continue to read each line and set it to `line` until it reaches null. Each time it reads a line, it checks if it does not contain AA or DD. If it does not contain either, then print the line. Edited it to fix an issue with it always being true.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
for (line=br.readLine(); line != null; line=br.readLine()) {
    if ( !((line.contains("AA")||line.contains("DD")) ) {
        System.out.println(line)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm, trying this gave no output and when I stopped the process it gave an exit code 130